# Perform the likelihood ratio test on a simple linear regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I am trying to study the likelihood ratio test for a simple linear regression $\hat y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma)$.  I am considering the null hypothesis $\Theta_0 = \{(\beta_0^\ast,\beta_1^\ast)\}$ against the alternative $\Theta_0^c$.  As I understand it, to test this hypothesis I want to find

$$\lambda(y_1,...,y_n) = \frac{\max_{\Theta_0}\mathcal{L}(\beta_0,\beta_1;y_1,...,y_n)}{\max_{\Theta}\mathcal{L}(\beta_0,\beta_1;y_1,...,y_n)}$$

Since $\hat y_i\sim N(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i,\sigma^2)$ then

$$\mathcal{L}(\beta_0,\beta_1;y_1,...,y_n) = 
\frac{1}{(2\pi \sigma^2)^{n/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_i)^2\right\}$$

and since $\Theta_0$ contains a single point then trivially

$$\max_{\Theta_0}\mathcal{L}(\beta_0,\beta_1;y_1,...,y_n) = \frac{1}{(2\pi \sigma^2)^{n/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\beta_0^\ast-\beta_1^\ast x_i)^2\right\}$$

and by definition of $\hat\beta_0,\hat\beta_1$ as the MLEs obtained from taking partial derivatives set equal to 0, we have

$$\max_{\Theta}\mathcal{L}(\beta_0,\beta_1;y_1,...,y_n) = \frac{1}{(2\pi \sigma^2)^{n/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1 x_i)^2\right\}$$

This then makes

$$\lambda = \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n[(y_i-\beta_0^\ast-\beta_1^\ast x_i)^2-(y_i-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1x_i)^2]\right\}$$

I want to know the distribution of this, I suppose, although it's here that I get confused about what this is and what I'm doing with it.  I suppose I want to reject the null hypothesis when $\lambda$ is adequately small but is it a probability distribution?  How do I know which one?